# How much data can be stored to the IE11 in-browser database within the windows 8 tablet

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

**Backgroud:**

I am building my offline application which stores data into the IE11 in-browser db (Indexdb)  using a pouchdb adapter.

**My questions:**

How much data can I store into the inbrowser-db within the IE 11. My application is intended to work in a windows 8 tablet environment.

There are two versions of IE available from my tabet (usual IE11 and the IE Metro). In terms of the amount of data that can be stored into the inbrowser db is there any difference between the two versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

From [the PouchDB FAQs](http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits):

> Internet Exporer 10+ has a hard 250MB limit, and will prompt the user with a non-modal dialog at 10MB.

There is also [this real-world research](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/24/indexeddb-and-limits-ie) that was done by Raymond Camden. You might also find ["Working with Quota on Mobile Browsers"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) to be useful.

I don't know if there's any difference between IE11 and IE Metro. If you do the research, please update the PouchDB FAQs and let us know. :)

Comment: In IE11, this can be increased to 1024MB by the user.  As far as differences go, there should be few differences in capability/feature support, though it should be noted that IE desktop is considered a different client than the Windows Store (FKA Metro) experience.  Consequently, databases are not shared between the browsers.  Also, there are reports that limits have been removed from the Edge browser.

Comment: Hi Lance Leonard , Thank you so much for the promt response. What do you mean by 'limits have been removed from the Edge browser'. What is the 'Edge browser' ?. What is the limit for the inbrowserdb for IE Metro.